# Set state of parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have an app with a few pages, the main `App` component holds the state of all changes made on all pages using a callback sent to the pages.

The last page of the app is an `Attachment` page with a browse button, the page renders an `AttachmentButton` component, with a callback sent to the `AttachmentButton` component. Then the parent page send the attached file with a callback to the upper `App` component.

All the pages' changes are being set properly on the upper `ticket` state beside of the attachment state, `this.state.ticket.attachment` is always `{}`.

Any idea what am I missing?

Attachment Page:

```
export default class Attachment extends React.Component {

  handleAddAttachment = file => {
    this.props.handleChange('attachment', file);
  };

  render() {
    const { ticket} = this.props;
    const { departments, request } = ticket;

    return (
        <div css={pageWrap}>
          <div css={attach}>Upload attachments here</div>
          <AttachmentButton handleAddAttachment={this.handleAddAttachment} />
           <AttachedFile />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

AttachmentButton component:

```
    export default function AttachmentButton({ handleAddAttachment }) {
      const handleUpload = file => {
        handleAddAttachment(file);
      };
      return (
        <div>
             <input type="file" css={selectButton} onChange={e => handleUpload(e.target.files[0])} />
              Select file
        </div>
      );
```

App component:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    ticket: {
      departments: '',
      request: '',
      exactRequest: '',
      attachment: {},
    },
  };

  makeHandleChange = (pageName, change) => {
    this.setState({
      ticket: { ...this.state.ticket, [pageName]: change },
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { ticket } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Router handleChange={this.makeHandleChange} ticket={ticket} />
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.ticket, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Final state:

```
{
  "departments": {
    "catId": 4,
    "catName": "Test"
  },
  "request": {
    "subCatId": 9,
    "subCatName": "test4"
  },
  "exactRequest": "12345",
  "attachment": {} //always empty
}
```

Comment: Are you getting proper values for `attachment` in the `makeHandleChange` function? Put a debugger there to check.

Comment: @tanmay Yes, I do, a `console.log(pageName, change)` results: `attachment File {name: "form.docx", lastModified: 1548312299641, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jan 24 2019 08:44:59 GMT+0200 (Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 23729, …}`

Comment: How are you checking this "final" state?

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb  `<pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.ticket, null, 2)}</pre>` on the `App` component.

Comment: And where is this line typed out? Which function and where in that function?

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ticket.attachment.file` is a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object, which is stringified as just `{}`. Hence it just shows `{}`.

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(new File([], "a"), null, 2))
```